# Image Sequence issues

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, image, video-sequence-editor

So Im working a on project where I have a image sequence playing on a 3d object, The sequence plays on the 3d object on the layout tab, but when I try to render the animation it only renders the 2d image sequence and not the image sequence and the 3d object together. Can anyone help with this issue.

Comment: It sounds like the image sequence is also in the video sequence editor. The render will default to anything in the video sequencer.